# Using compiled python file for QGIS script PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Is possible to use compiled python file (*.pyc) for "Open Existing Script ..." in the Scripts Processing module?

File dialog does not enable selecting `*.pyc` files.

I want to use QGIS scripts as PYC files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file you could just decompile it.  You could also write a short script to import it and use.